# Suggest chip for step-up from 3 to 12 volts

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Colleagues, Hi!

I'm designing simple driver to feed 12V LED strips with 3-cell accumulator - e.g. 3.2-3.7 Volts. The output current would not be greater than 400mA - and using less LEDs I can cut it to 150-200mA if necessary.

Initially I thought to use something like `MC34063A` but I'm not sure from its datasheet whether its internal circuit will work with VCC less than 5V.

So I'm open to suggestions whether I should use something different. You see, there is no need in very neat output characteristics (because it is just about leds) - so I believe I can even try to create step-up PWM from scratch, but I'm not sure I should try if I can find some ready solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try Linear Technology. Here's a snap shot of their search engine containing your parameters. It takes about 15 seconds to set up and gives you all the chips that may be suitable: -

[image]